# Create item to opensearch index, RuntimeException: Request cannot be executed; I/O reactor status: STOPPED

Tags: java, opensearch

When it tries to create new doc in the openSearch, I get an error

I have tried down-grading open-search-dependency version to match it with the course, still the same.

[attached image ->](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUwSr.jpg)

Was expecting that items/doc would be created in the opensearch database index.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Request cannot be executed; I/O reactor status: STOPPED

at org.opensearch.client.RestClient.extractAndWrapCause(RestClient.java:915)

at org.opensearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:301)

at org.opensearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:289)

at org.opensearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1762)

at org.opensearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1728)

at org.opensearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1696)

at org.opensearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.index(RestHighLevelClient.java:961)

at com.aviorn36.consumer.KafkaOpenSearchConsumer.createDocsInOpenSearch(KafkaOpenSearchConsumer.java:73)

at com.aviorn36.consumer.KafkaOpenSearchConsumer.main(KafkaOpenSearchConsumer.java:54)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request cannot be executed; I/O reactor status: STOPPED

at org.apache.http.util.Asserts.check(Asserts.java:46)

at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.ensureRunning(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:90)

at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalHttpAsyncClient.execute(InternalHttpAsyncClient.java:123)

at org.opensearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:297)

7 more
```

Rest-client for open-search.

```
    private static RestHighLevelClient getRestHighLevelClient() {
        String openSearchServerUrl = "http://localhost:9200/";
        URI openSearchUri = URI.create(openSearchServerUrl);
        RestClientBuilder restClientBuilder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(openSearchUri.getHost(), openSearchUri.getPort(), openSearchUri.getScheme()));
        if(openSearchUri.getUserInfo() != null){
            restClientBuilder.setHttpClientConfigCallback(
                    httpAsyncClientBuilder -> {
                            String[] authDetails = openSearchServerUrl.split(":");
                            CredentialsProvider basicCreds = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
                            basicCreds.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(authDetails[1],authDetails[2]));
                            httpAsyncClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(basicCreds).setKeepAliveStrategy( new DefaultConnectionKeepAliveStrategy());
                            return httpAsyncClientBuilder;
                        }
                    );
        }
        return new RestHighLevelClient(restClientBuilder);
    }
```

Comment: Do you need to rewrite this library? https://github.com/Aiven-Open/opensearch-connector-for-apache-kafka

Comment: @OneCricketeer , I have not used kafka connect or any connectors to send data to open-search. I have merely created High-Level-Rest-Client for open-search interaction. I am trying to explore and learn low-level kafka api, then move towards high-level apis like kafka-stream and connect. I have updated the description on how I have created rest-client for open-search. Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Hy, the error seems to come from KafkaOpenSearchConsumer, line 54. Can you post the concerned code ?

Comment: The above repo [also uses the opensearch rest client](https://github.com/Aiven-Open/opensearch-connector-for-apache-kafka/blob/main/src/main/java/io/aiven/kafka/connect/opensearch/OpensearchClient.java#L40). The Kafka client library isn't the issue here, anyway, therefore I've removed the tags. Create a [mcve], please. My question was if you tried Kafka Connect first, then decided to rewrite it